# Error in Opencart theme header

Tags: header, themes, opencart

I am using ancart template for opencart. These errors are shown

```
Notice: Undefined variable: small_html in /home/rythm321/public_html/catalog/view/theme/ancart/template/common/header.tpl on line 113
Notice: Undefined variable: org_html in /home/rythm321/public_html/catalog/view/theme/ancart/template/common/header.tpl on line 137
```

Here is the header file https://www.dropbox.com/s/7heyayzwoewjmqt/header.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if ($categories) {
   $org_html = "";
   $small_html = "";
```

To:

```
$org_html = "";
$small_html = "";
if ($categories) {
```

As the variables are defined within the `if` condition, they'll not get defined if the `if` condition returns false.

Have a nice day !!

Answer (score -1):

you should select "Show in the top menu" from the category edit menu each other.